# Apollo Cache - Partially read from cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, optimistic

I'm trying to achieve optimistic updates with apollo client.

I already have it working in different places in the app however I'm facing a wall here.

I'm running

```
store.writeQuery({query, variables, data});
```

within the `update` mutation callback and I tried to `store.read` it, it works fine. However, I can't manage to get this data from something else in the app.

The data I write to the cache is this:

```
{
                    playlist: {
                      __typename: 'Playlist',
                      elements: [{
                        __typename: 'Element',
                        id: 'test',
                        rating: 3,
                      }],
                    },
},
```

However, in the component where I want to use this cached data, my query is way more complex and I fetch way more fields. Not only that, but I also expect most of `playlist.elements` to be fetched from the network, only this specific one I expect to be coming from cache.

Is there to get only the element with the `id: 'test` updated, and the others updated from network normally ? Currently, I only get data from network and this cache written data doesn't seem to affect my query result.

Thank you :)

Comment: Optimistic updates are usually done by returning `optimisticResponse`, no? You seem to be permanently writing to the store. Maybe also using `writeFragment` can  help if you are just updating a single element. Find the documentation [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/caching.html#writequery-and-writefragment)

Comment: @Herku Unfortunately using `optimisticResponse` isn't an option here as I don't return the data I'd need in cache from mutation, but a boolean (`success: boolean` pretty much). Without going into implementation details, I will need to update cache and read from it.
Indeed I've checked the docs, but using a fragment didn't help, the data was still fully fetched from server ( or empty if using `cache-first` fetchPolicy.

Comment: Do you own the GraphQL implementation (as in you can change it)? Because it seems not very docmatic. Also I am no longer sure if we are talking about optimistic response (optimistic means it acts as a placeholder until the real result comes in). Maybe you are misunderstanding quite a lot of things about GraphQL. Best place to start would be reading the whole page I linked.

Comment: The whole idea of (optimistically) updating the cache is that you are (manually) syncronising the state with the server. This is why I don't understand why getting "all data from the server" is a problem. I think you are missing something else and it is hard to say without more code.

Comment: It mostly has to do with the GraphQL API. To cut a long story short, it's a wrapper over a REST API and there's not as much freedom as it'd be possible with a fully GraphQL API. With that being said, `writeFragment` and `readFragment` worked. Feels like I somehow reinvented the wheel here so I'll still investigate a more optimal solution, but as far as the question goes, that's a solved :)